# Django data save model without form in template

Tags: python, django

I want to save a value in the database when the button is clicked without using a form.
I want to save the value in h2 to another model when the button is clicked.
What can i do?

**TEMPLATE**

```
                                              <div class="widget-main">
                                                <center><h2 name="urun" value="{{ urun.urun_adi }} ">{{ urun.urun_adi }}</h2></center>

                                                </a>
                                                <input type="submit" onclick="location.href='{% url 'sepete_ekle' %}'"  value = "sepete ekle"  class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right">
                                                    Sepete Ekle
                                                </input>
                                                <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">{{urun.fiyat}} TL</a>
                                            </div>
```

**VIEWS**

```
def sepete_ekle(request):
if  request.method == 'POST':
    urun = request.POST["urun"]
    status = 0

    urunler = Siparis.objects.create(urun,status)
    urunler.save()
    messages.success(request, " Sepete Eklendi")
    return redirect('/bayi/profil_duzenle')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

**MODEL**

```
class Siparis(models.Model):
bayi = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name='bayi', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bayi',limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "BayiGrubu"})
urun = models.ForeignKey(Urun, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
adet = models.IntegerField()
tarih = models.DateTimeField()
status = models.BooleanField()
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Bayi Sipariş'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Bayi Siparişleri'
```

Comment: This while code looks incorrect to me, as the input(which is a self closing tag) is closed with a </inputa>, and what significance does the value attribute has in h2 tag?

Comment: I changed it but it has nothing to do with it. Clicking the button, I want to add the h2 value to the database. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Your requirement can be easily achieved with a form having one hidden input field and submit button i.e only a button will be visible to user. I can post code if you want with my suggested approach.

Comment: I would be glad if you send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the html posted by you in problem statement with the below one.

```
    <div class="widget-main">
      <center>
        <h2>{{ urun.urun_adi }}</h2>
      </center>
      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'sepete_ekle' %}">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ urun.urun_adi }}" name="urun" />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="sepete ekle"
          class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right"
        />
      </form>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">{{urun.fiyat}} TL</a>
    </div>
```

to know more about form hidden fields, here is a simple explaination for reference [check this out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-input-typehidden/)

Comment: actually this code will work. But the urun I want to register in the "Siparis" table did not match because it came from the Urun table. How can I solve it?

Comment: please update Urun model in problem statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Once try this, I hope it works.
Change view.py to this. Add an arguement to your function sepete_ekle.

```
def sepete_ekle(request,urun):
    if  request.method == 'POST':
        status = 0    
        urunler = Siparis.objects.create(urun,status)
        urunler.save()
        messages.success(request, " Sepete Eklendi")
        return redirect('/bayi/profil_duzenle')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

And urls.py to this:

```
path('/path/to/function/<urun>',views.sepete_ekle,name='sepete')
```

And in your html file:

```
<div class="widget-main">
<center><h2 name="urun" value="{{ urun.urun_adi }} ">{{ urun.urun_adi }}</h2></center>

 </a>
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href='{% url 'sepete_ekle' %}'"  value = "sepete ekle"  class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right">
                                                    Sepete Ekle
</input>
<a href="{% url 'sepete' urun.urun_adi %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">{{urun.fiyat}} TL</a>
</div>
```

So, when you click the button the h2 value will be sent in the url and in the view it will be taken from the arguement.

Comment: not working. Django said: sepete_ekle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'urun'

Comment: Once add urls.py, I don't know the exact url

Comment: And make sure the url should be exactly `path('/path/to/function/<urun>',views.sepete_ekle,name='sepete')` like this only.

Comment: Can you give another real example?